# SUBSTR & MOD invalid Identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on an assignment and am trying to figure out what my statement is giving me an ORA-00904: "SUBLOC": invalid identifier error. Can I not use the alias field in a MOD operator? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT Course_no, Location, TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(Location,2)) AS Subloc
FROM Section
WHERE Location LIKE '%M%'
  AND MOD(SubLoc,2) = 1
ORDER BY Course_no;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a column alias in the where clause where it is defined.  Use a subquery or CTE:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT Course_no, Location, TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(Location,2)) AS Subloc
      FROM Section
      WHERE Location LIKE '%M%'
     ) s
WHERE MOD(SubLoc, 2) = 1
ORDER BY Course_no;
```

Answer (score 1):

Gordon Linoff is right,
and you can use also in the where clause :
    **where mod (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(Location,2))) = 1**